# Запросы к базе данных MSSQL в высоконагруженном приложении

Tags: c#, sql-server

Хочу создать static class для работы с БД, содержащий методы для получения данных. Но дело в том, что обращения к методам класса могут происходить из разных потоков.

**Вопрос.** Как поведет себя подобный класс при одновременном обращении к одному из методов из двух разных потоков? (Будет ли он ждать, пока завершится первый запрос, произойдет исключение или запрос будет выполнятся в другом потоке?)

**Точнее:** Как правильно организовать запросы к БД осуществляя их из разных потоков?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заложить в подобной задаче статический класс, как фундамент работы с БД, означает отказаться от ООП и перейти к процедурному программированию, постепенно наращивая "мусорник", в лучшем случае разделенный на "хелпер" классы, "датасорсы" или еще чего. Более того, "контекст" БД обычно НЕ потокобезопасный, как и статика, и вам придется постоянно заботиться о синхронизации. Гораздо эффективней применить какую-либо **ORM** для работы с БД + (**UnitOfWork** + **Repository** + **Specification**). В данном подходе архитектура станет к тому же и тестируемой, чего не скажешь про сплошные статические классы и методы, протестировать которые можно только при помощи дополнительного кода в виде "врапперов". Для управления жизненным циклом объектов имеет смысл использовать один из существующих решений **DI/IoC**. Например в вашем случае можно на этапе настройки указать жизненный цикл для контекста БД "PerThread" и "контейнер" будет сам следить, чтобы в каждом потоке был свой, новый контекст или одна транзакция.

Comment: Незнаю, стоит ли использовать **ORM** или **Инъекции зависимости** на каждый поток для обработки запроса. В моей задаче запросы будут на чтение, а это как правило потокобезопасно. Да и сам **SqlConnection** MSDN: *"Любые открытые члены этого типа, объявленные как static, являются потокобезопасными. Потокобезопасность членов экземпляров не гарантируется."* Думаю что глобального connection будет вполне достаточно для работы с ним из разных потоков. Просто я не хочу *нагораживать*, добиться максимально эффективной работы от приложения. Надеюсь, что Вы ещё подскажите.

Comment: Я понял, вы хотите использовать минимум усилий и получить максимум производительности. К тому же запросы ограничиваются только выборками - уже проще. В подобной схеме ОДИН конекшен для всех потоков будет вполне рабочим подходом, то есть все потоки будут обращаться к БД в рамках ОДНОГО соединения. Если вас это устраивает - дерзайте. Но если вдруг вы решите добавить сюда операции изменения данных, то необъяснимых порой результатов работы программы вам не избежать (подозреваю будут ерроры связанные с доступом к одним и тем же данным на уровне БД).

Comment: Кстате из вашей цитаты из мсдн следует, что я и говорил - контекст БД НЕ потокобезопасный.

Comment: Вообще-то в документации шла речь о статических членах самого класса `SqlConnection`, а не статических экземпляров `SqlConnection`. С потокобезопасностью гарантирую проблемы и при чтении данных с использованием `DataReader`.

Comment: У Вас есть опыт? Что предлагаете использовать?